# Propensity score non parametric estimation

Tags: logistic, nonparametric, causality, kernel-smoothing, propensity-scores

In several papers, in the 'double machine learning' literature, the propensity score (a nuisance parameter) is estimated non parametrically. It is a bit unclear how this estimation is performed, as most often, only the properties of the nuisance estimation method are needed.

Are there `R` packages that estimate propensity scores, or in general logistic regression function $T=f(X)+\epsilon$, $T \in \left\{0,1\right\}$ non parametrically, in order to embody the non parametric methods mentioned in papers  (Kernel Regression, Neural Nets, Regression Trees, LASSO (for high dimensional data)) to estimate the nuisance parameter?

Edit : In the double machine learning literature, we often use non parametric methods to estimate the propensity score. I will focus on [Chernozhukov et al. (2018)](https://academic.oup.com/ectj/article/21/1/C1/5056401) as a main example. The authors mention several methods to estimate the nuisance parameters in pages 22-23. (lasso,random forests, sparse neural nets, deep neural nets).
I wanted to ask about how this estimation is happening, what are its parameters? what are its outputs? Let us suppose that I want to estimate the propensity score, in a partially linear model.
For example :1) LASSO : What is the model used ? In the parametric case, one can consider a binary GLM with an $l_1$ penalty and fit it.
2) Random Forest : One wants to estimate the functional relation between the binary treatment $T$ and the covariates $X$. (Suppose that the propensity model is $T=e(X)+v$, where $\mathbb{E}[V|X]=0$.) What is the random forest doing ? What loss is being used ?
I asked whether some codes are available in order to see how this estimation is performed and to know what are the 'parameters' in these non parametric methods.

Comment: Programming questions, incl. is there a package to do X in programming language Y, are off-topic on Cross Validated. Can you revise to clarify your statistical question(s)? You should consider including references to the "several papers".

Comment: @dipetkov: per [this meta thread](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5985/1352), I believe this question should stay open, since it quite emphatically requires statistical expertise to answer.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Even though I wrote a comment to the OP, I didn't vote to close this question. Can you please address your concerns to the users who voted to close. (At least I don't remember voting and I still can cast a vote rather than retract a vote, so I think I haven't yet voted.)

Comment: @StephanKolassa I've checked my Closure votes and I didn't in fact vote to close this question. You can see from my comment that I thought this question is relevant but poorly written, hence my suggestions to the OP. It's an interesting question, though somewhat lacking in references, so let's see what answers it gets.

Comment: @dipetkov: apologies, I got this question in my close votes review queue with two VTCs (of course I don't see who cast those), saw your comment and jumped to the conclusion you had cast one of the VTCs. Sorry about that, hope future close voters see my comment (and that this question gets a good answer).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I edited the  question.